# Cisco Routers and ACL with minimal interruption

Tags: cisco, ip, router, tcp, access-control-list

I have a Cisco 1921 router in which I have configured the following access control list:

EDIT 
    access-list 199 deny 192.168.1.24

```
access-list 199 permit any any
```

I want the ability to remove and add new access-list entries at any time for blocking IPs that I don't want to have internet access, and sometimes block all IP access.

How can I do this without interrupting internet traffic or all IP traffic for other IP address that should not be affected by changes?

For an example, when I remove the first access-list entry the permit option goes away and all internet access is lost until is re-entered into the system.

Comment: In my opinion this should be posted on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extended access lists.  This will allow you to both insert entries into existing ACL's as well as remove entries without having to remove/re-add the entire list.

So, for example:

`rtr-b(config)#ip access-list extended 199
rtr-b(config-ext-nacl)#100 deny ip host 192.168.1.24 any
rtr-b(config-ext-nacl)#1000 permit ip any any`

Which then results in an output that looks like this:

`Extended IP access list 199
    100 deny ip host 192.168.1.24 any
    1000 permit ip any any`

From this point I could, as mentioned, add more lines or delete existing lines.  I might insert a new rule by creating an entry numbered 90, or add one after 100 if that makes more sense.  The lines can also be resequenced (adding more available numbers).  More to the point, all of this can occur while the ACL is still applied to the interface.

[This](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_data_acl/configuration/15-sy/sec-data-acl-15-sy-book/sec-create-ip-apply.html) is a good place to start in the configuration guides about ACL setup in reasonably recent IOS versions.

Comment: @mxrx: It automatically switched the 1000 list to 199. I saw in my router there was no such thing as a 1000 list. Did you mean 100?

Comment: @mxrx: For some reason the router changed the 100 and 1000 lists into 199. It resulted in:


199 permit ip any any
199 deny ip host 192.168.1.24 any

which resulted in any ip being allowed access anyway. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes - you need to start the process in confit by typing "ip access-list extended 199" and then hitting enter.  After this you can enter the line number followed by the ACL.